# Administrating a git repo without root permissions

Tags: git, repository

I want to make a bare git-repo in my home directory accessible to my co-workers working on the same file system, allowing them to `git push` into it. However, I don't want them to be able to accidentally modify the repo with anything but `git`, so I can't just `chmod g+w` it.

Is this possible without being root? The only thing I could think of was setting the SUID bit to `git` so git could access the repo as me, but I don't know if that is really such a good idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) which deals with a lot of the hassle for you.

If you want to use plain git, you can do this:

To do this all of your co-workers and you need to be in the same group (e.g. developers). You can fix everything at once with:

```
newgrp developers
git init --bare --shared=group repo
```

but ofcourse you will get an empty repository. You can push your current work in there and continue from there.

If you do not use the git init path you will need to set the apprioprate permissions yourself as well as set the `core.sharedrepository=1` config variable.

Comment: Ultimately, I switched to [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/master-toc.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you're exposing your repo as a `file:///`, then file permissions will apply. As far as I know, git itself doesn't deal with "permissions". The mechanism you use to publish your repo takes care of that aspect (keys for ssh, .htacess or something for web).

---

This is untested but I think you should be able to setup a daemon using `git daemon` that your users can use to to push/pull from your repo. It will require read/write access to your repository but that's okay since it's running as you. Your users will be able to access your repo only using this. For details, check out the man page (`git help daemon`) and [this](http://book.git-scm.com/4_setting_up_a_public_repository.html). 
My original point, however, still stands. This is one way of *not* using the `file:///` protocol to expose your repository that doesn't require root privileges.

Comment: So is there no way to make the repo read-write-able for git but read-only without it?

Comment: +1 thanks, this works directly as long as no fine-grained permission settings are required

Comment: If it solves your problem, it's customary to "accept" the answer clicking on the tick. :)

Comment: @Noual Ibrahim: Sorry, yes. It is the accepted answer for now, but I also want to test gitosis and gitolite at some later point

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim: Remember also that if a bare repo uses a hook to perform post-receive checkout (for example), file permissions will come into play after push to the repo (when checkout writes to target dir).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use gitosis, or perhaps just something as simple as creating a new git user, and letting trusted users ssh into that account with ssh keys.

The latter doesn't really prevent people from accessing the files without using git, if that's important, spend the time to configure gitosis properly.

Comment: Creating a new git user requires administrative privileges.

Comment: @Noual Ibrahim: what would be the drawbacks of using my own account for gitosis? would that basically offer a way for everyone authorized by gitosis to directly ssh into my account?

Comment: @Tobias: More or less, yes, except that Gitosis relys on opensshd to only allow the user to run a very particular command, specified in the public key that has been authorized for that user.

Comment: @Noufal: Yes, creating the new git user requires admin privs, however, once done, further management can be done without admin privs, because gitosis makes everybody use the same user account. (It distinguishes between them by the fact that each user uses a different key).

Comment: Agreed Arfangion. However, the questioner asked for something which didn't require admin privileges.